# Inserting a new element after an existing element in an SVG (XML)

Tags: c#, svg, xml-parsing

I want to insert an element after an existing element. For example, in this simple XML file, I want to insert an element after the "defs" element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 790 790" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-rule="evenodd" xml:space="preserve" >
<defs >
<clipPath id="clipId0" >
<path d="M0,790 790,790 790,0 0,0 z" />
</clipPath>
</defs>
****I WANT TO INSERT MY NEW ELEMENT HERE
<g clip-path="url(#clipId0)" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.5" />
<g clip-path="url(#clipId0)" fill="rgb(0,255,0)" stroke="rgb(0,255,0)" stroke-width="0" >
<text transform="matrix(12.0023 0 -0 12.0023 130.206 546.583)" font-family="Arial,'sans-serif'" font-size="1.39636" >WORK REGION</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is my attempted c# code:

```
    public void AddBlackBackground(string xOrig, string yOrig, string xExt, string yExt )
    {
        XElement xE = new XElement("rect");
        xE.Add(new XAttribute("x", xOrig));
        xE.Add(new XAttribute("y", xOrig));
        xE.Add(new XAttribute("width", xOrig));
        xE.Add(new XAttribute("height", xOrig));
        xE.Add(new XAttribute("style", "fill:black"));

        XElement root = _XML_Doc.Root.Element("svg");
        XElement defs = root.Element("defs");
        defs.AddAfterSelf(xE);
    }
```

The XElements root and defs are null when I run the code, so naturally the line defs.AddAfterSelf(xE); throws an Object reference not set error.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What is `_XML_Doc`?

Comment: In the constructor of the parser class: _XML_Doc = XDocument.Load(_FilePath);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with namespace

```
var ns = _XML_Doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
XElement root = _XML_Doc.Element(ns +"svg");
XElement defs = root.Element(ns + "defs");
defs.AddAfterSelf(xE);
```

Or to ignore namespace

```
_XML_Doc.Root
  .DescendantsAndSelf()
  .Elements()
  .Single(d => d.Name.LocalName == "defs")
  .AddAfterSelf(xE);
```

Comment: Actually, that caused it to bomb on the line XElement defs = root.Element("defs");  root is null with that code as well :/

Comment: Yes, I see that it is loaded in the debugger.

Comment: Ah! The namespace. Gets me every time. Trying now.

Comment: Glad to have been of help